# unable to download previous version of ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

My laptop has ionic version 6.10.1  installed globally and I worked on it. But now i want to work on ionic version 3.20.1 because my tutorial demands it.
so I tried this command

```
npm -g install ionic@3.20.1 

ionic -v
```

Check the version of ionic installed, but again it shows me the version of ionic as 6.10.1.

Comment: Your dont need 3.x to use older version. Corrent version supports old versions.

Comment: You can always uninstall the package if required and install the version you need.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall

Comment: I've already did a project on version 6.10.1. If I uninstall the package does it effect my project

Comment: Please look at the NPM  Global & Local Package installation options and decide the best as per your needs.
[Global]: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally
[Local]: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-locally